# Explanation on Rails Associations - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model-associations

i'm new to rails and your help and advise would be much appreciated as i am finding this challenging

> Aim: i want the creator of the event to be able to select more than one user as
>   hosts for a created event (just like how facebook allows the creator of
>   a page to be be able to select users as admins of a created page). Is the below how my model and schema should be displayed?

i was aiming to build something like this image. Event1 i can select Ian & Jesse as hosts, Event2 i can also select Ian again as a host and select Emma

[image]

This is how i imagine it so far to be built (your guidance would be much appreciated):

```
models
user.rb
has_many events

event.rb
belongs_to user

host.rb
belongs_to user
has_many events
```

> schema

```
users
name
email

events
title
address
user_id

hosts
user_id
event_id
```

Comment: is your admin also a `User` model ? or a different model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started writing this as a comment but realised it was getting too wordy.

your model is broken ... an `event` has many users .. it doesn't `belong_to` a single `user`.

What you have is a many to many relationship between users and events which needs resolving through a join table (aka associative/junction table). You have gone some way to resolving this with the hosts table though this goes against the rails convention.

What you want is something like:

**models**

*user.rb*

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :events
```

*event.rb*

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

and create a join table that references the two models

```
users table
  name
  email

events table
  title
  address

events_hosts table
  user_id
  event_id
```

The rails convention is for the join table to be named by joining the two names of the tables it is joining lexically ordered - i.e. events before hosts, concatenated together to give `events_hosts`.

Alternatively, you can also create a join model if you prefer:

```
EventHost

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :event
```

and modify the `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `has_many :event_hosts` in the other two models - the database schema will remain the same.